# Best practice: how to handle data records with changing "schema" / "columns"

Tags: csv, hadoop, bigdata, avro, parquet

This is a best-practice question.

Our set up is a hadoop cluster, storing (log) data in hdfs. We get the data in csv format, one file every day. Running MR jobs in hadoop on these files is fine, as long as the "schema" of the file, especially the number of columns, does not change.

However, we are facing the problem that the log records we want to analyze eventually change, in the sense that columns might be added or removed. I was wondering if some of you would be willing to share your best-practices for these type of situations. The best way we can think of at the moment is to store the data not as csv, but in json format. However, this will increase (at least double) the required storage space. We also came along Apache Avro and Apache Parquet, and just started looking into this.

Any ideas and comments on this issue are more than welcome.

Comment: Just found this mailing list entry, discussing advantages of json vs. avro: [http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201208.mbox/thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201208.mbox/thread)

Comment: At the end we decided to go for Avro. Avro is able to handle schema changes, and has connectors to all major languages, incl. jaql (which is part of IBM's BigInsights).

Answer (score 1):

use Thrift and use elephant bird (twitter lib )  for using the related file input/output format .